# Add user to Notion by an API request?

Tags: notion-api

Does Notion has an API method to add access to a new user?

I'm building a content service. Users pay for it in Telegram with a subscription feature. Now those, who bought subscription get access to content in Notion. So, basically I'm looking for a method, that adds/revoke user's access from Notion's page.

Is there any?